# Sonarqube - Assigned Quality Profile leads to MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

i tried to to add a custom Quality Profile (simply a copy of default js Profile Sonarway) to my Project. If i do so i end up with the following Error Message:

```
### Error updating database. Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'XXXXX-js' for key 'uniq_project_qprofiles' ### The error may involve defaultParameterMap ### The error occurred while setting parameters ### SQL: UPDATE project_qprofiles SET profile_key=? WHERE project_uuid=? ### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'XXXXX-js' for key 'uniq_project_qprofiles'
```

Sonarqube System: Server Version 5.2, MySQL 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

We have this Issue since the Update from Version 5.1.2 to 5.2

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: What steps did you follow to end up with this error? I've just tried on a 5.2 SQ instance running on MySQL and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: 1. Menu -> Quality Profiles 
2. Create a new Profile
3. Select it
4. in Projects Field search a Project
5. try to check the checkbox next to the project -> Error

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error following this scenario. Are you able to reproduce this issue with another project?

Comment: Hi,
it doesn't matter which project or quality profile i choose - same error everytime.

Comment: It also doesn't matter what quality profile i choose.
Standard or Custom no matter what language i can't assign a Quality Profile to a project - i'm always getting this error Message.
Is there a way to check if the database is alright ?

Comment: Maybe you have unsynchronized cache which causes generation of the "incorrect queries". Please stop server, remove sonar/data/es directory, start server and create custom Quality Profile. Maybe it will help.

Comment: i tried that - no change of behaviour - same error. I have no problem on creating custom quality profile but on assining any profile to a project.

Comment: I'm still getting this after upgrading to sonar 5.3. 
I also tried mysqlcheck -> no errors found.

What options do i have besides throwing it all away and setting sonar up from scratch ? Can i export Something ?

Comment: Faced the same Issue today on sonarqube 5.4, had to delete all the tables and set it up from scratch. No idea how to solve this yet.. :(

Comment: Mee too, no Problems since Version 5.4

Comment: Same problem here on version 5.6

Comment: it happened again - Sonar Version 6.0 - same Error not possible to change profiles for a project :-(

Comment: we'll try to reproduce this issue on a test instance